# Limitations of popstate/pushstate and automatically running AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, url

From what I gathered, popstate/pushstate physically changes the url address whenever you click on an event. In the example page below, whenever you click on a link in the nav bar, the ajax is called and the url changes. However, if I was to copy the altered url address and enter that as the web address, it would send me to the homepage of the website. Is it possible for the user to go to that altered url and have the ajax automatically called that is related to the altered url address? If so, what function would I have to look for?

Website Demo Homepage:
http://html5.gingerhost.com/

Altered website address that still leads to the homepage and not the section "London"
http://html5.gingerhost.com/london

EDIT: I've found this helpful link but are there any other helpful tutorials or advice?
http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/examples/history/pepper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found out is yes. Using programs such as PJAX will automatically do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at backbone.js as an example. http://backbonejs.org

Given that your server must know how to respond to all your urls, in the most basic implementation when the DOM has loaded, you will want to parse the url to determine where you are in your app to know which AJAX calls to trigger and what views, etc to load.  You can achieve this without using a framework like backbone.js but I would highly recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, again if it is usefull : if you want easy implementation of such navigation,

you could use https://github.com/binarymind/jquery-navigate

to test that, just add in your head after the jquery script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/binarymind/jquery-navigate/master/navigate.js" ></script>
```

after just read the doc in the github and don't hesitate to ask me if any issue, would be pleased to help